# SVG as a background image in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to add svg as a background image and i am using a React-Native-Svg to generate my svg and I've been trying to add it onto

`<ImageBackground source{{'<svg>...'}} />`

But I cant manage to get a anywhere with it

If anybody could give pointers i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says you need to import the .svg file inside de Component:

```
import Logo from './logo.svg';
```

You can then use your image as a component:

```
<Logo width={120} height={40} />
```

From: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#use-with-svg-files